# Stopping the program when reading data from UART

Tags: c, avr, uart

I have this simple code:

```
while(1){           
    char dolar = gps_get_char();//read char from uart
    if ((dolar == '$') || (receive_dolar == 1)){
        receive_dolar = 1;

        gps_get_nmea(nmea_in, sizeof(nmea_in));
        rozloz_nmea();

        receive_dolar = 0;
    }       

    /*control running program*/
    if (tl2 == 1){ //flag button from interrupt
        LCD ^= (1 << LED_ON_OFF);
        tl2 = 0;
    }   
}
```

But when the GPS is turned off, so the program stops here:

```
char dolar = gps_get_char();//read char from uart
```

Where function gps_get_char();

```
char gps_get_char()
{
    unsigned int in = 0;

    do {
        in = uart1_getc();
    } while((in & UART_NO_DATA) || (in & UART_BUFFER_OVERFLOW));

    return((char) in);
}
```

**Any idea why the program is stopped?**

Comment: Because `!(in & UART_NO_DATA) || (in & UART_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)` is always true in the case you encounter. What have ***you*** tried?

Comment: I wanted to check if data are available.

Sorry, this is goog condition:
while((in & UART_NO_DATA) || (in & UART_BUFFER_OVERFLOW));

Comment: What have you tried to do about your problem? Have you tried using a debugger? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Unfortunately. I do not own debugger. :(

Comment: Are you programming on windows or on linux? There are readily available debuggers such as gdb

Comment: Sorry.
This program is for ATmega128. The programming environment AVR Studio 6.2.

Comment: Well I think AVR Studio has a built-in debugger. Just do a simple search...

Comment: This condition is bad.

while((in & UART_NO_DATA) || (in & UART_BUFFER_OVERFLOW))

Comment: A programmer without a debugger is kind of like a taxi driver without a car... how do you expect to get any job done at all if you don't have a debugger?

Comment: The problem I found and removed without the debugger.

It was enough to add this condition
if ((dolar = uart1_getc()) != UART_NO_DATA)

Comment: We have no idea what your problem was. You gave us nothing to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your current approach works, you are prone at losing UART data. You should really be using interrupts instead of polling. Have the interrupt fill a sufficiently large buffer and set a flag condition when it is done. Then, have the program process the buffer.

Cheers.